# Xamarin access to iOS binding QualtricsSurveyViewController

Tags: swift, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a bindings library for iOS, generated an APIDefintions & StructsAndEnums class using sharpie bind, added a native reference to the bindings library, set the framework properties accordingly, and added a native reference of the bindings library to the iOS proj.

In the AppDelegate class, I am trying to initialize the ViewController, but the app crashes with the message:

***Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'Qualtrics.QualtricsSurveyViewController'***

Here is my VC code:

```
public partial class QualtricsViewController : QualtricsSurveyViewController
{
    public QualtricsViewController(NSString nibNameOrNil, NSNumber bundle) : base(nibNameOrNil, bundle)
    {
        this.Init();
    }
    public QualtricsViewController(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        base.Init();
    }
    public QualtricsViewController()
    {

    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System);
        btn.Frame = new CGRect(20, 200, 280, 44);
        btn.SetTitle("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);

        var user = new UIViewController();

        btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(user, true);
        };
    }
}
```

Within the AppDelegate class I am calling it like this:

```
 var qualtricsVC = new QualtricsViewController();
```

I am relatively new to setting up Native Bindings. My Native Binding proj compiles correctly and everything **seems** to be fine, until I call the QualtricsSurveyViewController. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I notice that the constructor with no parameters does not call `this.Init();` nor `base.Init();`. Nor does it inherit from a base-class constructor - no `: base()`.  This likely means that the constructor is only there for some special purpose, and that you need to call one of the other two constructors to have it work properly. I believe this isn't xamarin issue, but a question "`how to correctly use/subclass QualtricsSurveyViewController`". Therefore, look for docs for that class or the module/nuget/whatever that contains it. Probably those will be `native ios docs`, not xamarin-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you're doing incorrect initializing with the viewcontroller.

Notice : if you create the class constuctor `public  QualtricsViewController(nibNameOrNil, bundle)` for the viewcontroller , it means the viewcontroller must come from Storyboard, and we can't initialize it programatically.

To solve the problem ,removing the constuctor should works.

```
public partial class QualtricsViewController : QualtricsSurveyViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System);
        btn.Frame = new CGRect(20, 200, 280, 44);
        btn.SetTitle("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);

        var user = new UIViewController();

        btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(user, true);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked indeed. Thank you.